# Aborted job restarts

Tags: queueable-apex

I have an enqueued job using `system.enqueueJob( new APEX_Job_Queueable() );`

This job is a long running job which makes callouts to retrieve date. The callout returns a **NextLink Url** which, when populated, indicates that there are more data to retrieve. I check some governor limits and, when 1 is reached, I stop the current job and reenqueue the same job to continue.

I need to interrupt the job while testing and so I often use the link **Abort**.
The job aborts as expected but after 2-3 minutes, the job restarts.

What is the cause of this restart ? Is it an expected behavior ? Is it related to the fact that I reenqueue the job ?

Thank you

Comment: I'm also running into this issue and also have a long running HTTP callout

Answer (score 1):

> What is the cause of this restart ? Is it an expected behavior ? Is it related to the fact that I reenqueue the job ?

This is definitely not expected behavior and most likely a platform bug.

Unfortunately, I don't have a solution, but can at least update this question with proof of reproduction.

[image: Job Aborted]

[image: Same Job continued]

If I hear back anything official from Salesforce, I will update this answer.