# Transaction Finalizers do not run when Queueable is "Aborted"

Tags: queueable-apex, transaction-finalizers

In my testing, it seems as though [transactions finalizers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_transaction_finalizers.htm) do not run when the Queueable is aborted (via `Apex Job -> Abort` or other means).

I'm unable to find any documentation confirming this.

Is this truly the case?

Seems like a major problem with any solution relying on them for mission-critical processes.

Comment: Are you talking about while the Queueable is in the Queued status, or Running status? I ask because the transaction finalizer is attached as the code runs, so if it hasn't run yet, no finalizer is attached. I guess it'd be important to check the timing, as well as figure out what actually happens during an abort process.

Comment: @sfdcfox so... something else is going on....  After I abort the job, Salesforce is starting it back up like 2 minutes later and it runs to completion.  Seems like a pretty significant platform bug :(

Same issue documented here:
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/394284/aborted-job-restarts

Comment: do you have a salesforce case? if so I can check and confirm.

Comment: @AvijitChakraborty I don't... Doing this in a scratch org, though.  I think it would be fairly straightforward to reproduce.